# PHPExcel issue when loading file (that makes no sense)

Tags: load, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

So the following code:

```
$csv_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("CSV");
$temp = rand();
echo $temp;
echo "<br/>";
$php_excel = $csv_reader->load("foo.csv");
echo $temp;
```

Outputs this (as expected):

```
207192412
207192412
```

Whereas the following code:

```
$csv_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("CSV");
$temp = microtime(true);
echo $temp;
echo "<br/>";
$php_excel = $csv_reader->load("foo.csv");
echo $temp;
```

Outputs this:

```
1431775661.6455
1431775661.645471
```

Why does `$temp` change? I tried using other random variables names, like `$nggyu`, and I still get the same issue.

What gives?

(Using PHPExcel version 1.81, on Ubuntu 12.04, with PHP 5.3.10)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my system

```
<?php 
include 'PHPExcel.php';
$csv_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("CSV");
$temp = microtime(true);
echo $temp;
echo "<br/>";
$php_excel = $csv_reader->load("foo.csv");
echo $temp;

?>
```

Output :

```
1431798431.3535
1431798431.3535
```

(Using PHPExcel version 1.80, on Windows 7, with PHP 5.5.6)